# How to Add The Image (GIF) to My Blog Created Using Markdown?

Tags: markdown

Recently I install the starter template blog using: `npx degit https://github.com/timlrx/tailwind-nextjs-starter-blog.git` from github. I want to add the image (gif) to my blog post, the image and markdown file in the same directory location.

I tried to use this syntax in my markdown file:

```
![gif image](./Insertion-sort.gif)
```

And then I tried to change the syntax:

```
<img alt='Insertion-sort' src='./Insertion-sort.gif' />
```

But the image did not show in my browser (Chrome).

[image]

Thanks.